# updating multiple inputs using onChange in a state array and display it onSubmit in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a simple app where I have a form with multiple inputs and a button.
I'd like to update the input values in a state array and display them on submit.
I'm trying to use use onChange to update input values but I don't know how exactly I'd could possibly do this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Info extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: [],
        toggled: false,
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

//display html when saved
//when edited, bring back the inputs

onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}

handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.value);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div className="info">
            <div>
                <h2 className="title"> Personal Information </h2>
            </div>
            <form action="#" noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className='personal-info'>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="fName"></label>
                        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" placeholder="First Name" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="lName"></label>
                        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="location"></label>
                        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="email"></label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="phone"></label>
                        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='personal-btn-groups'>
                   <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    )
  }
}
```

I've been always using query selectors to get input values in vanilla js and that seems to me easier way to do this
But I understand that I'm not supposed be using it when working on React.

I do not know exactly how I'd update the values of inputs with the 'onChange' event handler and update them in a state array to display later on. But this is exactly what I'd like to do... Can anyone enlighten me please?

Comment: Can `data` be an object, or an array is a must?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to store all input to `data` as object to avoid duplicate. `onSubmit` you simply take `this.state` and send it as the collected form data (I just logged the data here). For `handleChange` you need to make the handler dynamic so that it can work on as many form input as you wish. Hence, we are using `e.target` to access the current value entered and using the element's name (e.target.name) to save the data with it's value (e.target.value) to the state. Feel free to drop question if not clear.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Info extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        data: {},
        toggled: false,
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({ ...this.state, data: {...this.state.data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value } })
  }

  render() {
    return (
        <div className="info">
            <div>
                <h2 className="title"> Personal Information </h2>
            </div>
            <form action="#" noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className='personal-info'>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="fName"></label>
                        <input type="text" id="fName" name="fName" placeholder="First Name" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="lName"></label>
                        <input type="text" id="lName" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="location"></label>
                        <input type="text" id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="email"></label>
                        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="phone"></label>
                        <input type="tel" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone" onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='personal-btn-groups'>
                    <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
      )
  }
}

export default Info;
```

Comment: Hi, may I ask how can I possibly do this using a state array as well so I can use map() method?

Comment: The issue with array is that it adds duplicate data (because it saves new data onChange). A workaround will be to check for key in array if it exists and update else create a new key with corresponding value

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `this.setState` to store the values to react state. Here is an example of storing the input values to an object at `this.state.form`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Info extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      data: [],
      toggled: false,
      form: {}
    }
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
  }

  //display html when saved
  //when edited, bring back the inputs

  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
  }

  handleChange(newForm) {
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      form: {
        ...this.state.form,
        ...newForm
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="info">
        <div>
          <h2 className="title"> Personal Information </h2>
        </div>
        <form action="#" noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
          <div className="personal-info">
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="fName"></label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="fName"
                name="fName"
                placeholder="First Name"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  this.handleChange({
                    fName: e.currentTarget.value
                  })
                }
                value={this.state.form.fName}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="lName"></label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="lName"
                name="lName"
                placeholder="Last Name"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  this.handleChange({
                    lName: e.currentTarget.value
                  })
                }
                value={this.state.form.lName}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="location"></label>
              <input
                type="text"
                id="location"
                name="location"
                placeholder="Location"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  this.handleChange({
                    location: e.currentTarget.value
                  })
                }
                value={this.state.form.location}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="email"></label>
              <input
                type="email"
                id="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Email"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  this.handleChange({
                    email: e.currentTarget.value
                  })
                }
                value={this.state.form.email}
              ></input>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="phone"></label>
              <input
                type="tel"
                id="phone"
                name="phone"
                placeholder="phone"
                onChange={(e) =>
                  this.handleChange({
                    phone: e.currentTarget.value
                  })
                }
                value={this.state.form.phone}
              ></input>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="personal-btn-groups">
            <button type="submit">Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use individual properties in state for storing values

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class Info extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {}
}

//display html when saved
//when edited, bring back the inputs

onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log('state', this.state)
}

handleChange = (e, key) => {
    // dynamic key
    this.setState({[key]: e.target.value})
}

render() {
    const { fName = "", lName = "", location = "", Email = "", phone = "" } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="info">
            <div>
                <h2 className="title"> Personal Information </h2>
            </div>
            <form action="#" noValidate onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                <div className='personal-info'>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="fName"></label>
                        <input type="text" value={fName} id="fName" name="fName" placeholder="First Name" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'fName')}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="lName"></label>
                        <input type="text" value={lName} id="lName" name="lName" placeholder="Last Name" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'lName')}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="location"></label>
                        <input type="text" value={location} id="location" name="location" placeholder="Location" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'location')}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="email"></label>
                        <input type="email" value={Email} id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'Email')}></input>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <label htmlFor="phone"></label>
                        <input type="tel" value={phone} id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="phone" onChange={e => this.handleChange(e, 'phone')}></input>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className='personal-btn-groups'>
                   <button type="submit">Save</button>
                </div>
            </form>

        </div>
    )
  }
}
```